`dotnet tool install Amazon.Lambda.TestTool-8.0` fails with 401 (unauthorized) even with `--ignore-failed-sources`
I have a new .NET 8 Lambda project in Visual Studio 2022 (created with the default AWS Lambda template for VS).  I want to use the Mock Lambda Test Tool with it, but when I run the command to install it:
dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.TestTool-8.0
I receive the following error:
Unhandled exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.<<GetAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T](String filePath, Func`2 action, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T](String filePath, Func`2 action, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.GetAsync[T](HttpSourceCachedRequest request, Func`2 processAsync, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Protocol.PackageMetadataResourceV3.LoadRegistrationIndexAsync(HttpSource httpSource, Uri registrationUri, String packageId, SourceCacheContext cacheContext, Func`2 processAsync, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Protocol.PackageMetadataResourceV3.GetMetadataAsync(String packageId, Boolean includePrerelease, Boolean includeUnlisted, VersionRange range, SourceCacheContext sourceCacheContext, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Protocol.PackageMetadataResourceV3.GetMetadataAsync(String packageId, Boolean includePrerelease, Boolean includeUnlisted, SourceCacheContext sourceCacheContext, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.GetPackageMetadataAsync(PackageSource source, String packageIdentifier, Boolean includePrerelease, Boolean includeUnlisted, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.GetMatchingVersionInternalAsync(String packageIdentifier, IEnumerable`1 packageSources, VersionRange versionRange, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.GetBestPackageVersionAsync(PackageId packageId, VersionRange versionRange, PackageSourceLocation packageSourceLocation)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.ToolPackage.ToolPackageDownloader.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<InstallPackage>b__0()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.TransactionalAction.Run[T](Func`1 action, Action commit, Action rollback)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Install.ToolInstallGlobalOrToolPathCommand.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<Execute>b__1()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Install.ToolInstallGlobalOrToolPathCommand.RunWithHandlingInstallError(Action installAction)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Install.ToolInstallGlobalOrToolPathCommand.Execute()
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.Invoke(ParseResult parseResult)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)

I've tried it with and without the --ignore-failed-sources flag.  Still same error.
What is going wrong?  I've searched this error online and found many potential solutions, but none have worked for me.

Does the library version in your layer match the declared framework of the Lambda?

@RossBush by "library version" are you referring to the .NET version that my AWS Lambda project is running on?  It is .NET 8.0 and the output type is Class Library (which is the default created by the template).  My aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json also specifies dotnet8 and I am also using the latest version of Amazon.Lambda.Core.  Anything else I should check?

Generally, f you create a Lambda layer that does not match the target framework of the Lambda then you can get slammed with exceptions.

@RossBush every "layer" of my Lambda is .NET 8 (unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by layers)
